# How to remove a launcher from Cinnamon main menu

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, cinnamon, launcher

I am running cinnamon desktop on Ubuntu 20.04.  I want to remove a launcher from the Other section of the main menu.  How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The menu editor app is documented at https://www.mankier.com/1/cinnamon-menu-editor

https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2018/06/15/tweaking-cinnamons-menu-in-linux-mint/ and https://blog.softhints.com/linux-mint-19-how-to-edit-main-menu/ show how to remove that item:.

- Right-click Menu
- Configure
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to Menu
- Open the menu editor
- Pick the Other sub-menu
- Un-check the tick box